# Почему емкость контейнера (capacity) самостоятельно увеличивается?

Tags: c++, stl

вот простенький код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> v(5); // в запасе есть 5 элементов

    cout << v.capacity() << endl;

    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(6);

    cout << v.capacity() << endl; // почему capacity самостоятельно увеличилась до 20?

    return 0;
}
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему емкость (capacity) самостоятельно увеличилась до 20, я ожидал что будет 6

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Вы же поместили в контейнер 6 элементов. Стратегия наращивания ёмкости у вектора достаточно сложная.

Одна из стратегий - 2^n - увеличивать ёмкость контейнера по степеням двойки.

Конкретная стратегия [зависит от реализации](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560904/vector-memory-allocation-strategy).

Цель такого поведения - уменьшить количество операций перераспределения памяти, так как они очень дороги по времени.

Comment: зачем. я ведь могу и сам резервировать память. но спасибо за ответ

Comment: @perfect, можете, но многие не делают. Более того, требовать от пользователя постоянно следить за памятью это не путь абстракций, к которым стремится C++. Поэтому никогда не стоит надеяться на то, что capacity вернёт известный Вам результат.

Answer (score 12):

Здесь вам уже хорошо объяснили, *как*. Давайте я скажу ещё пару слов о том, *почему*.

Дело в том, что увеличение capacity — дорогая операция. В основе `std::vector` лежит обыкновенный массив, который в принципе нельзя расширить.* Так вот, capacity как раз и показывает размер этого массива.

Как происходит увеличение capacity? Очень просто: аллоцируется *новый* массив, все элементы текущего копируются туда, старый массив уничтожается. Да, это довольно дорогая операция, оно может вызывать копирующие/перемещающие конструкторы элементов массива**. Поэтому желательно делать её как можно реже, её стоимость — `O(n)`, где `n` — текущая длина массива.

Допустим, мы не знаем размер нужных данных заранее, и кладём их в `std::vector` динамически, при помощи `push_back`. Если мы на каждом шаге будем производить копирование, при достижении размера `N` нам придётся сделать 1 копирование на 2-ом шаге, 2 на 3-ем, 3 на 4-ом, ..., `N-1` на `N`-ом. Итого количество копирований получается `N*(N-1)/2 = O(N^2)`. Для размера массива в 1000 элементов это порядка миллиона копирований!

Поэтому были придуманы стратегии по уменьшению количества копирований. Популярная стратегия — увеличение capacity по степеням двойки. Посмотрим на асимптотику при этом. Пусть финальный размер массива `N`, `k` — степень двойки такая, что `2^k <= N < 2^(k+1)`. У нас копирование происходит теперь не каждый раз, а всё реже и реже: после 1-го шага (1 элемент), после второго (2 элемента), после 4-ого (4 элемента), после 8-го (8 элементов) и т. д. Итого `1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k = 2^(k+1) - 1 < 2*N` копирований. Таким образом, количество копирований остаётся `O(N)` (за счёт менее оптимального расхода памяти).

---

*Нет, `realloc` тоже не выход, там память точно так же копируется в новый кусок, просто это от нас скрыто. Плюс не выполняются конструкторы/деструкторы.

**Если у класса есть перемещающий конструктор, объявленный как `noexcept`, то будет вызван он, иначе копирующий. Спасибо @gbg за подсказку.

Comment: Уточню - конструктор перемещения будет вызываться только в том случае, когда он объяелен как noexcept http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166001/resize-on-stdvector-does-not-call-move-constructor

Comment: И все же realloc копирует далеко не всегда, особенно для действительно больших массивов (по крайней мере в Linux для них делается remap). Также я бы добавил, что популярная стратегия степеней двойки всегда требует выделения нового участка, т.е. никогда сумма ранее выделенных участков не равна требуемому новому размеру (imho в apple выбирают новый размер 1.6 от старого (я иногда использую 3/2 + 1))

Comment: @gbg: Ого, даже так? Не знал. Добавлю в ответ.

Comment: @avp: Хм, а что такое `remap`? (Я объяснял на степенях двойки потому что там самые простые вычисления. У вас по сути тоже степени, но не двойки, а числа 1.5.)

Comment: @VladD [`mremap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mremap)

Comment: да, именно он. Пока искал http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man2/mremap.2.html (это адаптивное поведение гугла как-то мне не нравится) @D-side угадал.

Comment: Ага, понял, спасибо! Но вторая часть всё ещё представляет проблему — не выполняются конструкторы/деструкторы.

Comment: Верно. Почему они не могут это реализовать -- не понимаю (впрочем я очень многого в крестах не понимаю, вот и не пользуюсь ими (и другим не советую))

Comment: @avp: Проблема в том, ваш тип blittable или нет (не соображу, как это по-русски). В сишных традициях почти все типы такие, поэтому их можно перемещать через `memmove` или тот же `mremap`. Но если тип содержит в себе внутренние указатели на аллоцированную память или там на соседние элементы, так просто перемещать его в памяти уже не выйдет. (По этой же причине в C++ нет и не может быть нормального сборщика мусора.)

Comment: @VladD, в C++ есть сборщик мусора. Спорить о степени его нормальности не буду — не пробовал.

Comment: @ixSci: Вы имеете в виду boehm gc? Ну так он налагает требования на то, чтобы он мог найти указатель. Шаг вправо/шаг влево, XOR trick или хранение указателя не туда, и у вас забирают вашу казалось бы валидную память. Чтобы GC работал, нужно по сути обходиться с указателями как с C#-ссылками, а не как с числом.

Comment: @VladD, я имел ввиду [вот это](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Allow_garbage_collected_implementations). Конечно, gc в C++ никогда не будет таким как в C#, но он там такой и не нужен. Нужна лишь базовая поддержка

Comment: @ixSci: Ого, _strict pointer safety_. Если такую штуку сделают, то да, нормальный GC станет возможен. Но при этом многие техники обезбашенной работы с указателями (например, обфускация указателей на уровне рантайма, чтобы предотвратить срыв стека) станут намного сложнее.

Answer (score 8):

*Емкость(capacity)* - это количество элементов, под которое зарезервирован фрагмент памяти. Вектор сам занимается наращиванием памяти. 
Есть заблуждение, что перераспределение памяти происходит **ТОЛЬКО** при добавлении нового элемента, превышающего текущую емкость. Это не так, как @gbg отметил, у каждого компилятора стратегия распределения своя и вектор действует согласно этой стратегии.

Например, если вы запустите ваш код на компиляторе Visual Studio С++, то несмотря на то, что вы зарезервировали память под 5 элементов, то уже после добавления первого элемента в вектор, емкость увеличивается до 7.

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v(5); // в запасе есть 5 элементов

    cout << v.capacity() << endl;

    v.push_back(1);

    cout << v.capacity() << endl; // здесь емкость увеличивается уже до 7

    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(6);

    cout << v.capacity() << endl; // почему capacity самостоятельно увеличилась до 20?

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод приложения у меня следующий

```
5
7
15
```